# Homogeneous material: mathematical definition

Tags: terminology, symmetry, definition

What is the mathematical definition of a homogeneous material (relative to a given property)?

Comment: Homogeneity means that symmetry group acts transitively, i.e. given two points $p$, $q$ you can find a symmetry (transformation preserving properties you are interested in) which maps $p$ to $q$.

Answer (score 1):

If the material is endowed a coordinate system $x$, and the "property" in question is some local operator, i.e. a mapping, $f(x)$, from the point in the material to some vector space, then a homogeneous material would have have the property that $f(x)$ is a constant. More generally you'd have some function which is defined in a neighborhood around $x$.

Consider the polarization of a material. This is described by a [polarization vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_density) $\vec{P}(\vec{x})$. If the material has homogeneous polarization, then the vector, $\vec{P}$, does not change with $\vec{x}$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \vec{P} = 0$.